# Generate Log file only when the flag is true - NLog

Tags: c#, logging, dll, nlog, dllimport

I am using NLog in my C# DLL project and the target path for the log file is the temp directory.
Now I have to pass a flag(true/false) to the Dll and generate the log file based on the flag value.
Means if the flag is true, then I have to generate the log file into the temp folder.
If the flag is false, then do not generate a log file. Is there any solution to do this in C# project with NLog

Comment: What exactly is your question? "How to pass a variable to a DLL"? You pass those to methods or constructors, not to DLLs. That being said, a DLL shouldn't write its own logs, it should accept a logger interface and write to that, letting the calling application decide where and how to log.

Comment: See [how to configure nlog from code](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Configure-from-code)